# AngularJS animation when model changes

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I have been searching on Google and Stackoverflow but haven't found what I am looking for.

Here's what I have. I promise I am making a sincere effort at figuring this out.

The problem is as follows: I have animations working with the list.  When I add items to the list using the timeout, they correctly animate in.  However, the "title" variable is a string.  I want to apply an animation when this value changes.  I am still clueless right now honestly on how to get that to work.  I understand that I can add css classes for animations for ng-hide, but I still don't quite understand how to fit that here.  Any help is appreciated in advance.  Please enlighten me.  You don't have to give me code.  Even a high level description of how to accomplish this will suffice.

```
// app.js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ngAnimate"]);
  // route configuration
}());

// homecontroller.js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("MyApp");
  app.controller("HomeController", ["$scope","$timeout", homeController];

  function homeController($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = ["Frodo", "Bilbo", "Merry", "Pippin", "Sam"];
    $scope.title = "The Hobbits";

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.title = "The Hobbits and the Wizard";
      $scope.items.unshift("Aragorn","Faramir","Boromir");
    }, 5000);
  }
}());
```

Some HTML

```
<!-- view for HomeController -->
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<div ng-controller="HeaderWebpart.HeaderController">
  <div class="testClass" style="display:block;" ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
div.testClass.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: enter 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000);
  animation: enter 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
@-webkit-keyframes enter {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
      height: 0px;
      left: -70px;
    }
    75% {
      left: 15px;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
      height: 20px;
      left: 0px;
    }
}
div.testClass.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: this site might be helpful: http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. As you can see, there is an `.animate` class when the actual animation is run. In addition, there is an `.infinite` class that can get added to continually repeat the animation (not over a set time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have nothing that applies any animation logic to the `<h1>` element, simply assigning a value to `title` within a controller is not enough.

If you have a look at the documentation for angular animations 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate - you'll see that only a specific set of directives have animation hooks. Each of these directives usually have a pairing of enter/leave or add/remove animations. This means that angular adds and removes specific CSS classes to these elements, which you can use to perform animations with, similar to what you have already done with the `ng-repeat` directive and `testClass` animations above:

```
.yourAnimationCSSClass.ng-enter { }
   => what your element should look like before the animation starts
      what the change should be and the duration

.yourAnimationCSSClass.ng-enter.ng-enter-active { }
   => ending(stable) state for your animation, ie. what the 
      element should look like when you're done
```

... `ng-leave` and `ng-leave-active` work similarly.

So, to solve this for your `<h1>` element, one way to apply an animation is to optionally set a CSS class using `ngClass`. This ends up being fairly close to the [Class and ngClass animation hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations#class-and-ngclass-animation-hooks) example in the Angular developer guide for animations, so have a look at that example.

Comment: It's usually possible to do some minor template magic with your elements such as `ngClass=" title != '' ? 'myAnimationCSSClass' : '' "`, `ngIf="title != ''"` or `ngShow="title != ''"` to make your code a bit more terse or to use different animation hooks if you already have some defined, but everyone might not appreciate the approach. Any of these should allow you to just write to the scope variable in your controller and apply an animation without triggering it manually, though.

Comment: orbitbot - Thanks for the response.  Used this in conjunction with what others said.  Cheers. :D